# Why does $L = \{ 0^n 1^n \space | \space n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ belong to $\mathrm{P}$?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, regular-languages, finite-automata

My professor said that the *non-regular* language $L_{1} = \{ 0^n 1^n \space | \space n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ belongs to $\mathrm{P}$. I do understand that all regular languages belong to $\mathrm{P}$ as it's easy to determine and so can be computed in $\mathcal{O}(n^k)$, but why do most *non-regular* languages not belong to $\mathrm{P}$ but $L_{1}$ does? Is it also possible to give an example of a language $L$ that does not belong to $\mathrm{P}$?

Comment: What is k? I believe that you can compute $L_1$ in $O(n)$ (or at most squared n in Turing Machine model).

Comment: @user777 $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily write a polynomial-time algorithm to decide $L_1$ (just count the zeros and check you see the same number of ones), so the language is in $\mathrm{P}$.

Most non-regular languages are not in $\mathrm{P}$ because there are uncountably many languages in total, but only countably many languages in $\mathrm{P}$.

The halting problem is not in $P$. If you want a computable example then, by the [time hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem), any language that is $\mathrm{EXP}$-complete is not in $\mathrm{P}$.

<sub>This answer is intentionally brief because all the things I've mentioned are well-known facts that you should be able to look up, now that you know what to look for. If you need more detail, I suggest asking a new question about that, after checking that we don't already have a question about it.</sub>